# Visual Studio 2008 Output Window UTF-8 Char Show

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

How to write UTF-8 Char (Ş,İ, arabic letter) in Visual Studio 2008 output window?

Comment: Utf-8 is a encoding that uses **bytes**, there's no such thing as a "UTF-8 Char".  If you got it in a string then it is too late, it already got mangled.  Ş,İ is not an arabic letter afaik.

Comment: okay, try this, I have a string that contains (Ş, İ, vݒ ,ݤ ,ݕ , etc.) and then How to I write Visual Studio 2008 output window this string?

Comment: You use Debug.Print() to write text to the Output window.  Which writes the Arabic glyphs just fine on my machine, in spite of the 5000 mile culture gap.  Still pretty clueless what "Ş, İ" might mean, I hope you do.